# On a sentence from "To Haydon", a poem by Keats

Tags: pronunciation, sentence-meaning, poetry

Here's '[Addressed to Haydon](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Addressed_to_Haydon)', a poem by John Keats:

```
High-mindedness, a jealousy for good,
 A loving-kindness for the great man's fame,
 Dwells here and there with people of no name,
 In noisome alley, and in pathless wood:
 And where we think the truth least understood,
 Oft may be found a "singleness of aim,"
 That ought to frighten into hooded shame
 A money-mongering, pitiable brood.
 How glorious this affection for the cause
 Of steadfast genius, toiling gallantly!
 What when a stout unbending champion awes
 Envy and malice to their native sty?
 Unnumbered souls breathe out a still applause,
 Proud to behold him in his country's eye.
```

I'm not fully sure of the meaning of these two lines:

> What when a stout unbending champion awes
>
> Envy and malice to their native sty?

Do they mean

> What, for example, happens, when a stout unbending champion awes
>
> Envy and malice to their native sty?

As an aside, I'm also curious how should one rhyme 'gallantly' and 'sty': should one end them both in [ai] or in [ee]?

Comment: I read that line as *[What [When an unbending stout champion] awes]*. *Champion* is used as a verb here, I think. I think I'd read both *gallantly* and *sky* normally; *sky* has *eye* to rhyme with already. But of course, I'm not the best person to read English poems around here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *As an aside, I'm also curious how should one rhyme 'gallantly' and 'sty'*

To answer your aside, that may be an example of an *eye rhyme* (sometimes called a *sight rhyme*). Poets sometimes embed these "visual rhymes" into their poetry. As [one website](http://www.trellismagazine.com/RightWordOct.html) explains:

> Two words that look alike but do not sound alike are called *eye rhyme*. They are pleasing to the eye, and writers can use them for a visual effect in a poem, but they do not match to the ear.  They fail to rhyme.

Moreover, the [Your Dictionary](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples/examples-of-rhyme.html) website mentions, under a list of the types of rhymes:

> **Eye rhyme** - The rhyming in this type is based on spelling and not sound. Examples are: *move* and *love*, *food* and *good*, *death* and *wreath*.

You can see an eye rhyme in this Emily Dickinson excerpt:

> We slowly drove – He knew no haste
>   And I had put away
>   My labor and my leisure too,
>   For His Civility

That said, identifying an original eye rhyme can be tricky business. Regional pronunciations vary. The word *been* may rhyme with *when* or *seen*, depending on the speaker's preference; in the U.S., the word *creek* may rhyme with *bleak* or *stick*, depending on where you are from. This gets even more complicated the longer a poem endures. As Wikipedia mentions:

> Many older English poems, particularly those written in Middle English or written in the Renaissance, contain rhymes that were originally true or full rhymes, but as read by modern readers, they are now eye rhymes because of shifts in pronunciation, especially the Great Vowel Shift. They are called *historic rhymes*.

---

As for your main question, that construct is not a common one; Milton started a question with it in *Paradise Lost*:

> What when we fled amain, pursu'd and strook
>   With Heav'ns afflicting Thunder, and besought
>   The Deep to shelter us? this Hell then seem'd
>   A refuge from those wounds: or when we lay
>   Chain'd on the burning Lake? that sure was worse.

The OED references this passage, under their entry for *what*:

> With ellipsis, esp. of the remainder of the question; hence (colloq.) short for ‘What did you say?’ or ‘What is it?’

So I'd say your interpretation seems like a pretty good one.

By the way, if the only difficulty you are having with that Keats poem is the meaning of *what when*, then you're doing pretty good!